# Configure Data Source - Struts 1.3.8

Tags: tomcat, struts, datasource

how to configure data source in struts-config.xml in struyts 1.3.8 ?

My Sample Data Source:

```
<data-sources>
 <data-source type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" key="dbSource">
            <set-property property="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <set-property property="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore" />
            <set-property property="username" value="root" />
            <set-property property="password" value="sf~007tech" />
  </data-source>
  </data-sources>
```

Code:

```
dataSource = (DataSource)servlet.getServletContext().getAttribute("dbSource");
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `data-sources` element in `struts-config.xml` was deprecated and removed in struts 1.3, as detailed in the [upgrade notes](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsUpgradeNotes12to13). I think it would be preferred to configure the datasource in the web container and do the look up through JNDI. Instructions can be found in the [tomcat wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingDataSources).